# Obtaining scene change frames with corresponding timestamps and scene scored saved in a text file

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

I have to use FFmpeg to detect shot changes in a video, an also save the timestamps and scores of the detected shot changes? How can i do this with a single command?

> ### EDIT

I jumped to my use case directly, as it was solved directly using FFmpeg, without the need of raw frames.

Comment: What is *shot change*? You mean scene change?

Comment: Yes, scene change, let's say the video switches from one camera to another.

Comment: See [select filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#select_002c-aselect), you can detect scene changes using it programmatically.

Comment: @oguzismail Thanks for that. But for generating the expression value, I need the frame somewhere to process it, say for eg: compare pixels with some other image, and decide whether to pass that frame to output or not. Can you help with that? My main concern was to obtain the intermediate frames before passing them to output. Also, it'll be great if you can share your method of programming to detect scene change using this filter.

Comment: This is an example from the link above "Create a mosaic of the first scenes:
`ffmpeg -i video.avi -vf select='gt(scene\,0.4)',scale=160:120,tile -frames:v 1 preview.png`"

Comment: Seerch  the internet for yuv4mpegpipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and perfect solution I came across after reading tonnes of Q/A:
Simply use the command:

```
ffmpeg inputvideo.mp4 -filter_complex "select='gt(scene,0.3)',metadata=print:file=time.txt" -vsync vfr img%03d.png
```

This will save just the relevant information in the time.txt file like below:

```
frame:0    pts:108859  pts_time:1.20954
lavfi.scene_score=0.436456
frame:1    pts:285285  pts_time:3.16983
lavfi.scene_score=0.444537
frame:2    pts:487987  pts_time:5.42208
lavfi.scene_score=0.494256
frame:3    pts:904654  pts_time:10.0517
lavfi.scene_score=0.462327
frame:4    pts:2533781 pts_time:28.1531
lavfi.scene_score=0.460413
frame:5    pts:2668916 pts_time:29.6546
lavfi.scene_score=0.432326
```